# Closures and Counter stacking

Tags: javascript, closures

So I've been trying to get to grips with closures and on the whole I feel like I have a pretty good grasp of the basics,

So I've been working with a setInterval function like so;

```
function addTimer(elementID,cssColor,time){
  counter = 0;
  function timeIt(){
    $(elementID).text(counter);
    $(elementID).css("color", cssColor);
    counter ++;
  }
  setInterval(timeIt, time)
}

addTimer("#timerTag", "red", 1000)
addTimer("#tt", "blue", 1000)
addTimer("#ttt", "pink", 1000)
```

So each time I add newTimer object, the html counter will increment by an extra one for each object I add, so one addTimer object and it will increment by one, two it will increment by two and so forth...

Any clarification as to why this is the case would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Always [use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), your [mistake](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) would then have produced an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out what the issue was for anyone curious, I was declaring the counter variable without the var keyword causing it to be bound to to window object, rather than independently to each new function call.